# How to Create URL Link Button for custom objects to pre-fill fields when creating new record

Tags: button, url, link

I'm trying to create a 'New' button using the Link button with URL. This is for my custom object that I need to pre-fill when the New button is clicked. For example, I have CustomObjectA that has a related list view for CustomObjectB

[image]
When I click the button New, it should show the form with the default values.
I wrote the syntax as below:

```
/lightning/o/CustomObjectB__c/new?defaultFieldValues=Field1__c={!CustomObjectA__c.Field2__c}
```

the syntax has no error, but when I clicked the button, it's not populated by default. What should be the proper URL then?

Answer (score 0):

I used this URL button and it is working. Is your case different with some other text field ? Try checking parameters and API name of field. Hope this helps.
PS - Do check [limitations](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.links_considerations.htm&type=5) of url buttons before implementation.
Screenhots:
[image: Button Setting]

[image: Test Value and button]

[image: Default Populated Value]

Comment: Hi KKumar, thank you for this. I tried a text type field and it works but when I tried populating lookup fields. it's not pre-populating. Does this supposed to work on lookup fields also?